# How to release Flutter default app to the App Gallery

Tags: flutter, huawei-developers, appgallery

1. I have developed the Flutter application for Android and iOS and already release it to the app store and play store. I want to release my App to the App Gallery (Huawei). Please guide me to continue the process.
   Can I use the same app without any further configurations ?
   how can I test the app before releasing it to AppGalery?
2. I tried to add the android app to the console but the option disabled . any explanation?
   [image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please note, you need to create an app first in order to add it into your project. The following should be the info. you needed. Please make sure to follow the steps:

To Create a project in AG: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-createproject-0000001100334664

To Create an app in AG: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-createapp-0000001146718717

To test your app in AG: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-test-overview-0000001107794814

To release your app in AG: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-release-overview-0000001272395372